# How to play sound using media plugin in ionic2

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have read ionic2 documentation form ionic site. And successfully added the cordova plugin for media. But when i am using media.create() method then nothing happened.when i try to debug the app using VS code with browser then this error arrives "

```
core.es5.js:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): cordova_not_available
    at g (polyfills.js:3)
    at l (polyfills.js:3)
    at Function.t.reject (polyfills.js:3)
    at MediaPlugin.value [as create] (decorators.js:57)
    at SessionPage.startPlay (session.ts:49)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SessionPage.html:16)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11852)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13060)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12648)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8830)
    at core.es5.js:9419
    at HTMLImageElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.es5.js:2674)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:4136)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
```

"

And when i am try to debug using android studio then i am not able to find out the src folder.
**if any body have implemented media plugin in ionic2 please help me.**

Comment: cordova plugins dont work with ionic serve.. they are mobile based.. only works with emulator/device

Comment: Try to run your app on an emulator or real device. Thanks